# Extending redux-toolkit slice

Tags: redux-toolkit

I've got an interesting topic for you this time around. I am a little stuck with this topic since I've tackled it a few month ago.

I am trying to extend a redux toolkit slice:

EX: I have a slice defined, but I would like to add some more reducers. Or to override some reducers.

This I've manage to do with this:

```
//Extend slice function
/**
 *  @remarks
 * 
 *  This method extends an already declared slice in oreder to attach custom actions to the reducer.
 * 
 *  @param slice The root slice you want to extend
 *  @param caseReducers The case reducers you want to add to the current ones. Current slice reducers won't be override.
 *  @param extraReducers Extra reducers to add to the slice. Don't use this for slices that contain extra reducers! They will be overridden!
 *  
 * 
 *  @returns slice: Slice
 *  The extended slice containing the current reducers concatenated with the new caseReducers and with the extraReducers 
 *
 */

export const extendSlice = ( slice: Slice, caseReducers?: ValidateSliceCaseReducers<any, SliceCaseReducers<any>>, extraReducers?: ( ( builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<NoInfer<any>> ) => void ) ) => {
  return createSlice( {
    name: slice.name,
    initialState: slice.getInitialState(),
    reducers: { ...caseReducers, ...slice.caseReducers },
    extraReducers
  } );
};
```

I was wondering if I can do the same thing with the `extraReducers` like I did with the `caseReducers` to oveeride/extend them. Or is there a point to do. Are the `extraReducers` inside the `caseReducers`? Asking this since I have no access to the `extraReducers inside the slice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap them instead:

```js
function extendSlice(originalSlice, caseReducers, extraReducers) {
  const wrappingSlice = createSlice({
    name: slice.name,
    initialState: slice.getInitialState(),
    reducers: caseReducers,
    extraReducers
  } );


  const wrappedReducer = (state, action) => wrappingSlice.reducer(originalSlice.reducer(state, action), action);
  return {
    ...wrappingSlice,
    reducer: wrappedReducer ,
    caseReducers: {
      ...wrappingSlice.caseReducers,
      ...originalSlice.caseReducers
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But is this preserving the extrareducers from the originalSlice?

Comment: Is it ok if I ask you for a breaf explination of what is going on here? For some people, including me, might look a little intimidating. Please explain how are the extraReducers preserved.

Comment: The extraReducers are preserved because you still call the original reducer function.
You essentially create a new reducer function and keep the original slice's reducer function. Then you call `const intermediateResult = oldReducer(state,action); const finalResult = newReducer(intermediateResult ,action)` - or `const result = newReducer(oldReducer(state, action))`. Remember: reducers are just functions. `newReducer` will call the new case reducers and extraReducers, `oldReducer` will call the old reducers and extraReducers.

Comment: That is more than I was expecting. if this works, hats of to you mate :D

Comment: Sorry. Don't you get an error if you use typescript on the `wrappedReducer`?

Comment: The type for that would probably be `(state: YourStateType, action: AnyAction) => YourStateType`.

Comment: `const wrappedReducer = (state, action) => wrapperSlice.reducer(slice.reducer(state, action));`

This line is having this error: `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`

Comment: I am not sure if the `wrappingSlice.reducer` should be called with the `originalSlice.reducer(state, action)` since, the `wrappingSlice.redicer` expects an action aswell. Should we add the action to the `wrappingSlice.reducer(originalSlice.redicer(state, action), action)` ??

Comment: Sorry yeah, correct :)

Answer (score 0):

The previouse response is as valid as this one. I just added the posibility to override the slice completly override the slice. The sad part is that the extraReducers are never preserved in eighter cases. Too bad. Just copy the extra reducers from the original slice and append the new ones. Anyway, just swap the `originalSlice.reducer` with `wrappingSlice.reducer` in the `wrappedReducer` declaration. If you leave it as `phry` suggested, the initial state will not be overridden.

```
export const extendSlice = ( originalSlice: Slice, caseReducers?: ValidateSliceCaseReducers<any, SliceCaseReducers<any>>, extraReducers?: ( ( builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<NoInfer<any>> ) => void ), newName?: string, newInitialState?: any ) => {

  const wrappingSlice = createSlice( {
    name: newName || originalSlice.name,
    initialState: newInitialState || originalSlice.getInitialState(),
    reducers: { ...caseReducers },
    extraReducers
  } );
  const wrappedReducer = ( state: RootState, action: any ) => originalSlice.reducer( wrappingSlice.reducer( state, action ), action );
  return {
    ...wrappingSlice,
    reducer: wrappedReducer,
    caseReducers: {
      ...originalSlice.caseReducers,
      ...wrappingSlice.caseReducers
    }
  };
};
```

NOTE: For the ease of use, I recomend the version iside the question unless you know very well what you are doing. Cheers!